# distinct count in mysql group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the unique count of the domains using apps.

The below query does not fetch any results. However if run the same query without distinct it returns the counts

```
SELECT 
  apps, category, COUNT(distinct(domain)) as counts
FROM table1.techs
GROUP BY apps
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` is not a function, so the brackets serve no purpose:

```
SELECT 
    apps, category, COUNT(distinct domain) as counts
FROM table1.techs
GROUP BY apps, category
```

Also, more importantly, you must list *all* non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause to get meaningful results, OR remove `category` entirely from query.